# MySql При получении данных из двух таблиц возникает ошибка: Column 'название колонки' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, select, codeigniter, join

Есть две таблицы связанные по двум колонкам

в одной таблице (**monitoring_companies**)
есть колонки

- mc_id (id элемента)
- c_id (id страны покупателя)
- generator_c_id (id страны производителя)

обе эти колонки имеют идентификаторы стран , названия которых **c_name**  хранятся в другой таблице **countries**

таблица **countries**
имеет две колонки

- c_id (id страны)
- c_name (название страны)

Мне нужно получить массив с названиями стран покупателей и производителей

Использую конструктор запросов фреймверка codeigniter

Запрос выглядит следущим образом

```
$this->db->select('mc_id')
    ->group_start()
        ->select('c_name AS name')->from('countries')->where('countries.c_id = monitoring_companies.c_id')
    ->group_end()
    ->or_group_start()
        ->select('c_name')->from('countries')->where('countries.c_id = monitoring_companies.generator_c_id')
    ->group_end()
->from('monitoring_companies');

    $getresult = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

выдает ошибку.

> Not unique table/alias: 'countries'

Выходит, мне нужно задать псевдоним таблице 'countries'

Задаю псевдоним:

```
$this->db->select('mc_id')
    ->group_start()
        ->select('c_name AS name')->from('countries')->where('countries.c_id = monitoring_companies.c_id')
    ->group_end()
    ->or_group_start()
        ->select('c_name')->from('countries AS cscsdc')->where('cscsdc.c_id = monitoring_companies.generator_c_id')
    ->group_end()
->from('monitoring_companies');
```

тогда выдает ошибку

> Column 'c_name' in field list is ambiguous

Если напишу просто вот так:

```
$this->db->select('monitoring_companies.mc_id')
    ->group_start()
        ->select('c_name AS name')->from('countries')->where('countries.c_id = monitoring_companies.c_id')
    ->group_end()
->from('monitoring_companies');
```

то получаю массив, но как видно в массиве хранится всего одна страна связанная по id покупателя

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mc_id] => 1
            [name] => Коморские острова
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mc_id] => 2
            [name] => Бангладеш
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mc_id] => 3
            [name] => Коста Рико
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mc_id] => 4
            [name] => Конго
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [mc_id] => 7
            [name] => Коморские острова
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [mc_id] => 23
            [name] => Россия
        )

)
```

еще попробовал такой вариант

```
$this->db->select('monitoring_companies.mc_id')
    ->group_start()
        ->select('buy.c_name AS name')->from('countries AS buy')->where('buy.c_id = monitoring_companies.c_id')
    ->group_end()
    ->or_group_start()
        ->select('gen.c_name')->from('countries AS gen')->where('gen.c_id = monitoring_companies.generator_c_id')
    ->group_end()
->from('monitoring_companies');
```

получил огромный массив с более чем 1000 элементами.

хотя в таблице  **monitoring_companies** их 6...

перепробовал десятки вариантов, но как получить массив в котором будут храниться обе страны так и не понял...(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке означает следующее: есть как минимум 2 разные колонки (в разных таблицах) или 2 разные таблицы с таким именем, и сервер не знает, какую из них использовать.

Добавьте обеим копиям таблиц разные алиасы (это Вы сделали, но только для одной из таблиц - сделайте так для обеих, но с разными алиасами), и укажите эти алиасы в именах используемых полей (колонок). Т.е. не `c_name`, а, скажем, `cscsdc.c_name`.

PS. Рекомендация - как только количество таблиц в запросах становится более 1 (неважно, одна и та же или разные) - всем таблицам присваивайте алиасы. и всем полям указывайте алиасы таблиц. Серверу всё равно, а от подобных ошибок уберегает.

PPS. Почему так сложно? попробуйте по-простому

```
$this->db->select('m.mc_id, c1.c_name as name1, c2.c_name as name2')
         ->from('monitoring_companies as m')
         ->join('countries as c1', 'm.c_id = c1.c_id')
         ->join('countries as c2', 'm.generator_c_id = c2.c_id');
```

Comment: что то все-таки не так... не обратил сразу внимание. вместо нужного массива получился массив с более чем 1000 элементами..  дополнил вопрос кодом внизу

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов А почему Вы используете `group_start` вместо простейших `join`?

Comment: за знал бы я, как...)) наверное надо селект на join заменить и убрать группировку, это вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Добавил возможный код в ответ.

Comment: Решил вставить всe значения в одну таблицу и задача усложнилась...
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868930/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D0%B8c%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-alias-%D0%B8-join-%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: Появился интересный вопрос. А что если я захочу достать из таблицы данные предварительно отфильтровав их по какому то значению?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883521/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC