# Как извлечь данные из двух таблиц с иcпользованием alias и join? Скрины, примеры моего кода внутри

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Есть две таблицы которые содержат:

1. id анкет
2. содержимое полей заполненных анкет

связанные по ключу an_id (id анкет).

как выполнить запрос чтобы получился массив из акет содержащих список значений своих полей?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 3
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1533301181
            [last_name] => кукум
            [name] => кукумsfdv
            .....
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 4
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1533304656
            [last_name] => Иванов
            [name] => Иван
            .....
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 5
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1533304884
            [last_name] => Семенов
            [name] => Семен
            .....

        )

)
```

Вот скрины таблиц для наглядности:

**список анкет**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**список значений полей анкет**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

использую фреймверк codeigniter

с помощью конструктора запросов написал вот такой код:

```
$this->db->select('
    an.*,
    fval.pfld_value as last_name,
')
->from('users_anket as an')
->join('profile_fields_value as fval', 'an.an_id = fval.an_id')
->where('pfld_id',1);//где id поля равен 1
```

для того, чтобы получить значение одного поля из второй таблицы (список значений полей анкет) запрос подходит, но как обратиться к этой же таблице но уже извлечь поле (список значений полей) под другим id, да еще и назвать их своими именами, я не могу понять.

мне как то нужно написать что следующее значение поля я буду извлекать из ячейки где id равен 2. В голове решение писать только несоклько селектов и каждый раз придумывать новые псевдонимы полей.

Comment: Во-первых, чем придумывать псевдонимы полей и хардкодить их в приложение, разумнее один раз создать таблицу, которая устанавливает однозначную связь между идентификатором и именем поля, и использовать её в запросе. Во-вторых, из EAV получить желаемую структуру несколько затруднительно. Получай записи со структурой `Array
        (
            [an_id] => 5
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1533304884
            [field_name] => last_name
            [field_value] => Семенов
        )` и уже на клиенте конвертируй в нужную структуру.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM анкеты t1 JOIN значения t2 ON  t1.ID=t2.анкета_ID JOIN имена t3 ON t2.поле_ID = t3.ID`

Comment: @Akina
у меня есть такая таблица,как ее подвязать чуть позже разберусь, пока явно задам названия полей Про структуру не совсем понял. У меня сейчас и так получается массив такого вида, где из второй таблицы хранится только фамилия. Какой именно должен получиться массив на выходе чтобы его можно было конвертировать? Можете оформить вторую часть комментария в ответ? чтобы был ровный код, может быть получится разобраться

Comment: Не, я разбираться синтаксисом codeigniter не имею никакого желания.

Comment: @Akina. да это я просто комментарий отредактировал) выполнил запрос, получил огромный массив и распарсил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно делать джоин для каждого поля при этом в джойне указывать критерий для поля. Вот как можно получать last_name и first_name

```
$this->db->select('
    an.*,
    ln.pfld_value as last_name,
    fn.pfld_value as first_name,
')
->from('users_anket as an')
->join('profile_fields_value as ln', 'an.an_id = ln.an_id AND ln.pfld_id = 1')
->join('profile_fields_value as fn', 'an.an_id = fn.an_id AND fn.pfld_id = 2');
```

Нужно больше полей - делайте больше джойнов

Comment: но это неправильная конструкция. Тут сразу видно. from и первый join у вас идут вместе. дальше стоит ; и конструкция начинается со стрелки. со стелки она начинаться не может. псевдомним ln а в `an.an_id = fval.an_i` все тот же `fval` но даже если сделать все правильно то для второго join нет ни своего from ни select. Но за наводку спасибо. Немного поправил ваш ответ и получилось

Comment: Интересный вопрос который несколько усложняет этот, а что если я захочу извлечь данные, отфильтровав их по какому то значению? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883521/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC

Comment: Добавляйте условие в join
`->join('profile_fields_value as ln', 'an.an_id = ln.an_id AND ln.pfld_id = 1 AND ln.pfld_value = "Петров" ')`