# Как выбрать данные из нескольких таблиц с фильтрацией по определенным значениям

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Считаю вопрос очень важным так как нигде ранее не встречал, поиск всех значений по одной большой таблице в которую они все записаны.

На сайтах, где была настроена хоть какая нибудь фильтрация выборка идет из таблицы где все поля раскиданы по колонкам и по нескольким таблицам, но не свалены в одну.

теперь суть моей задачи:

Есть три таблицы
таблица с **id анкет** пользователей `users_anket`

вот ее скрин для общего представления

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она связана с другой таблицей **значений** `profile_fields_value` по полю `an_id`,

а это сама таблица `profile_fields_value`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она связана с третьей таблицей **названий полей** `profile_fields` по полю `pfld_id`

вот ее скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для выборки данных из этих таблиц написал вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT *
    FROM gmcrm_users_anket table1 
    JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields_value table2 ON table1.an_id=table2.an_id 
    JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields table3 ON table2.pfld_id = table3.pfld_id
    WHERE table1.an_status = 1
```

в итоге в php на выходе получаю длинный массив который я уже группирую и обрабатываю.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 79
            [pfld_id] => 1
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => Петров
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => last_name
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 80
            [pfld_id] => 2
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => Петр
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => name
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 81
            [pfld_id] => 3
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => Петровчи
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => otchestvo
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 82
            [pfld_id] => 4
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => 1
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => sex
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 83
            [pfld_id] => 5
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => 10,10,1925
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => date_of_birth
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 84
            [pfld_id] => 6
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => Россия
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => grajdanstvo
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 85
            [pfld_id] => 7
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => 4434
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => series_of_pass
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 86
            [pfld_id] => 8
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => 0884
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
            [pfld_name] => num_of_pass
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
            [pfild_group_name] => passport_data
            [pfild_group_status] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [an_id] => 2
            [an_status] => 1
            [an_date] => 1534938430
            [pfldv_id] => 87
            [pfld_id] => 9
            [uid] => 0
            [pfld_value] => отделом уфмс россии
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [p_f_m_str] => 
            [pfldv_revision] => 0
```

и т.д

**Вопрос:** Как мне изменить запрос (вставить в него дополнительные параметры для поиска по конкретным значениям? то есть не только где table1.an_status = 1 (эта часть выборки была простой) но и

где например  name='Петр' и last_name="Петров"

вижу что все нужные мне данные собраны в одном столбце таблицы   `profile_fields_value` где объединяющим для них полем является `an_id`

Попробовал эти варианты

```
SELECT *
    FROM gmcrm_users_anket table1 
    JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields_value table2 ON table1.an_id=table2.an_id 
    JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields table3 ON table2.pfld_id = table3.pfld_id
    WHERE table1.an_status = 1 and table1.an_id in 
    (
        SELECT sub.an_id
        FROM gmcrm_profile_fields_value sub
        WHERE 
        (pfld_id=2 and pfld_value ='Петр') OR (pfld_id=1 and pfld_value='Петров')
        GROUP BY sub.an_id Having COUNT(sub.pfld_value) = 2
    )
```

и такой

```
SELECT *
    FROM gmcrm_users_anket table1 
    JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields_value table2 ON table1.an_id=table2.an_id 
    JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields table3 ON table2.pfld_id = table3.pfld_id
    WHERE table1.an_status = 1 and table1.an_id in 
    (
        SELECT sub.an_id
        FROM gmcrm_profile_fields_value sub
        WHERE (pfld_id, pfld_value) IN(
            (1, 'Петров'), (2, 'Петр')
        )
        GROUP BY sub.an_id Having COUNT(sub.pfld_value) = 2
    )
```

когда ищу Петрова Петра запрос выполняется 0,3с, но если я ищу Петрова Ивана запрос выполняется уже 15 секунд. То же самое и с Ивановым Иваном.(запрос выполняется почему то 15 сек)

Неужели при таком способе хранения данных в таблице извлечь из нее нужную группу значений нельзя?

Мне говорили что такой способ хранения в бд будет самым лучшим так как извлечь все нужные данные из одной таблицы быстрее через из n-ного количества связанных. Но пока пользы не увидел.

это план выполнения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для множественных условий получаете id интересующих записей как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506507/194569 (`(pfld_id, pfld_value) in( (1,'Петров'), (2, 'Петр') )`) а потом уже к ним подклеиваете ваш запрос для получения подробностей по ним

Comment: в MySQL так не выйдет(динамическое кол-во полей), по крайней мере в 1 запрос без пост обработки

Comment: @Mike можете развернуть комментарий в ответ, я прочитал ответ по ссылке. но из за отсутствия опыта, не могу получить нормальный результат, возможно не хватает какого то or and или знака..

Comment: Он практически ни чем не будет отличаться от того запроса, который вам дали в ответе. только там не учтено, что pfld_id то же надо проверять, что бы не найти случайно "Петра" в каком нибудь другом поле. А что касается его скорости работы - тут думаю вопрос наличия индексов. для правильного варианта, с проверкой и типа поля и значения, должен быть индекс из этих двух полей (pfld_id, pfld_value)

Comment: ну у вас full scan таблицы, конечно он тормозить будет, видимо все таки индекса по полям (pfld_id, pfld_value), о котором я сказал ранее у вас нет

Comment: @Mike не совсем понимаю куда копать? о чем речь? вот смотрите? у меня в одной таблице хранятся названия полей profile_fields,и таблица profile_fields_value которая связанна с предыдущей по полю pfld_id. Вот посмотрите в вопросе. я сделал скрины этих двух таблиц. pfld_id является primery_key в таблице profile_fields. А что за индекс такой? - не понимаю.. еще какую то колонку нужно добавить?

Comment: @Mike спасибо! повесил индексы на поля, связывающие каждую пару таблиц и запрос сократился стал меньше секунды. Осталось только понять, в каком случае нужны индексы в каком они бесполезны а когда вредны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте написать ваше условие в подзапрос, типа такого:

```
    SELECT *
        FROM gmcrm_users_anket table1 
        JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields_value table2 ON table1.an_id=table2.an_id 
        JOIN gmcrm_profile_fields table3 ON table2.pfld_id = table3.pfld_id
        WHERE table1.an_status = 1 and table1.an_id in 
    ( SELECT sub.an_id FROM gmcrm_profile_fields_value sub 
        WHERE sub.pfld_value ='Петр' OR sub.pfld_value ="Петров"
       GROUP BY sub.an_id Having COUNT(sub.pfld_value) = 2 )
```

Comment: не совсем понял. Я точно знаю что в базе нет Петрова Виктора. И если я впишу вместо петрова петра именно Петрова витора, то все равно в ответ получу таблицу со списком полей от Петрова. Как же сделать поиск и по петрову и по петру?

Comment: тогда в подзапрос можно добавить группировку и условие Having где указать сколько полей должно совпадать, если и Пётр и Петров значит  Having COUNT(sub.pfld_value) = 2. выше отредактировал свой ответ

Comment: Если захочу отобрать еще и по дате рождения то прикручу еще один or и Having COUNT(sub.pfld_value) увеличу на 1?

Comment: да, всё верно ...

Comment: ответ не подоходит, так как запрос занимает более 13 секунд, и это только при поиске среди 13 анкет, представлю что будет когда анкет будет более 1000

Comment: @Александр Думаю стоит все таки учитывать pfld_id, что бы не найти случайно "Петр" в каком нибудь другом поле. Особенно актуально будет если будут искать по каким нибудь числовым полям, так что стоит сделать вроде `(pfld_id=2 and pfld_value ='Петр') OR (pfld_id=1 and pfld_value='Петров')` или более кратко `(pfld_id, pfld_value) IN( (1, 'Петров'), (2, 'Петр') )`

Comment: @Mike дополнил свой вопрос двумя вариантами с использованием ваших подсказок.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Покажите все индексы, которые есть на таблице и план выполнения (explain plan) и скажите много ли у вас Ивановых (любых)

Comment: ивановых может быть так же тысячи, об этом как раз нужно позаботиться заранее.  индексов (то есть уникальных полей всего 144)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Индексы - это то, что создается командой create index (или create key( или тоже самое в момент создания таблицы в едином запросе с созданием

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83470/discussion-between---and-mike).